# How to get author et al et header in latex?

Tags: latex

is there a way to have: author 1 et al. in the header rather than the 5 authors? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\title{Title of the paper}
\shorttitle{Short title of the paper}

\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3, Author 4, Author 5, and Author 6}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\title{Title of the paper}
\shorttitle{Short title of the paper}

\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3, Author 4, Author 5, and Author 6}
\leftheader{Author 1 et al.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{document}
```